# How to store and retrieve images in sql server database through VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

SQL Server supports the ability for clients to store
objects within tables.

Create Field that data type Image and Initialize byte array with a null value initially.Use FileInfo object to get file size.Open FileStream to read file.Use

Answer (score 5):

Do a little googling before posting here. Below is the third search result I got for your query. I know how to do this, but not enough patience to do it again. So here is a sample code from [TechArena](http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1124120.htm)

> ```
> Function SaveImage _
>    (ByVal FileName As String) As Integer
>
>    ' Create a FileInfo instance
>    ' to retrieve the files information
>    Dim fi As New FileInfo(FileName)
>
>    ' Open the Image file for Read
>    Dim imgStream As Stream = _
>       fi.OpenRead
>
>    ' Create a Byte array the size
>    ' of the image file for the Read
>    ' methods buffer() byte array
>    Dim imgData(imgStream.Length) As Byte
>    imgStream.Read(imgData, 0, fi.Length)
>
>    Dim cn As New SqlConnection _
>       (ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("cn"))
>    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Images_ins", cn)
>    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
>
>    With cmd.Parameters
>       .Add("@FileName", VarChar, 100).Value = _
>          fi.Name
>       .Add("@FileType", VarChar, 10).Value = +
>          fi.Extension
>       .Add("@Image", Image).Value = imgData
>       .Add("@FileSize", Int, 4).Value = fi.Length
>    End With
>
>    cn.Open()
>    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>    cn.Close()
>    cn.Dispose()
> End Function
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The image field in SQL Server is simply a byte array.  Here is the significant code you will need.  Let's assume the name of your image field in the database is "imageField".  Hope this helps.

To retrieve an image and save it to disk:

```
//dr is a DataReader returned from a SELECT command
Dim imageInBytes As Byte() = dr("imagefield")
Dim memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = _ 
    New System.IO.MemoryStream(imageInBytes, False)
Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = _ 
    System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
image.Save("c:\image")
```

To save an image into SQL Server from disk:

```
''Get the image file into a Byte Array
Dim image As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\image.jpg")
''Add the byte array as a parameter to your Insert/Update SQLCommand
parameters.Add("@ImageField", image)
```