# How to save an resized image to database which is uploaded to server in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to save an image which is resized using Imageresizer plugin to database.
Here is my code.

```
<HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Async Function Edit(ByVal employeeMaster As EmployeeMaster, ByVal upload As HttpPostedFileBase) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        Try
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                    If upload IsNot Nothing Then
                        'Dim imageData As Byte()= New [Byte](upload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}          // this section saving to database which is original file ----- start
                        'upload.InputStream.Read(imageData, 0, CInt(upload.InputStream.Length))
                        'employeeMaster.Photo = imageData  // --- end

                        Dim guid1 As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                        Dim filename = guid1
                        Dim versions = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
                        Dim path1 = Server.MapPath("~/Content/")
                        versions.Add("", "maxwidth=600&maxheight=600&format=jpg")
                        For Each suffix As String In versions.Keys
                            upload.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                            ImageBuilder.Current.Build(New ImageJob(upload.InputStream, path1 + filename, New Instructions(versions(suffix)), False, True))
                        Next
                        Dim savedFileName = Path.Combine(path1, Path.GetFileName(filename))

                        Return File(savedFileName, "application/octet-stream", filename)
                        upload.SaveAs(savedFileName)
                        Dim imageData As Byte()= New [Byte](upload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}     // trying to save new image to database ----- start
                        upload.InputStream.Read(imageData, 0, CInt(upload.InputStream.Length))
                        employeeMaster.Photo = imageData  // -----end
                        Dim size1 = upload.ContentLength
                        Dim fullPath As String = Request.MapPath("~/Content/" + filename)
                        If System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath) Then
                            Dim ex = "ok"
                            System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath)
                        End If
                    End If
                    db.Entry(employeeMaster).State = EntityState.Modified
                    Await db.SaveChangesAsync()

                    Dim json1 = New With {Key .message = "Updated Successfully", Key .error = "False"}
                    Return Json(json1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
                Else
                    'logic for when that description exists
                    'for example, to add to ModelState
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmployeeCode", "EmployeeCode Exists")
                End If
        Catch ex As DbEntityValidationException

        End Try
    End Function
```

The uploaded file can be directly save to database. But I am compressing that image using Imageresizer plugin. Then it is saving to a folder.I am trying to read that saved image which is in the folder and save newly formed image to database. How can be it done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store and retrieve images in sql server database through VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397708/how-to-store-and-retrieve-images-in-sql-server-database-through-vb-net)

Comment: The method is diffrent. I have solved myself. Answer is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
Here is the code

```
Dim _fileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(savedFileName)
                        Dim _NumBytes As Long = _fileInfo.Length
                        Dim _FStream As New System.IO.FileStream(savedFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)

                        'upload.SaveAs(savedFileName)
                        imageData = New [Byte](_FStream.Length - 1) {}
                        _FStream.Read(imageData, 0, CInt(_FStream.Length))
                        employeeMaster.Photo = imageData
```